# How to import gcc compiled C code in Eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile

I am facing some issues in Importing Old C code to Eclipse.

1. I have a huge C code which has multiple main files. The code compiles in Linux terminal using GCC. I am able to add the code and binaries into eclipse.
   how to compile the code in eclipse saying this is my main file?
   Atleast how to debug the code using a binary?(binary runs but unable to debug the code)
2. I want to try the second method  of creating an eclipse project through the gcc compiler from the linux terminal.

System has eclipse helios version.(around 2010)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How do you build the binaries outside of Eclipse? Do you have for example a Makefile? -- OT: Why at all do you use such an outdated version of Eclipse?

Comment: Yes I have a Makefile.  My office supports only that Eclipse. Thing is Code is very old, that has to be debugged in eclipse . To debug code i have added entire path to eclipse. But unable to debug or compile. To compile , I have 10 main files. I have to compile one of it. It's huge code, i can't segregate files also. So, how to do this.